# How to sort custom object, that has a list of list

Tags: java, comparator

```java
public class StdResponse extends CommonResponse{
    
    private int claimsMatched;
    private String employeeId;
    private List<StdDetails> stdDetails;

}

public class StdDetails {
    
    private String claimId;
    private String type;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private String reportedDate;
    private String hrStatus;
    
}
```

I have a StdResponse object "response". Now i want to sort this response object with startDate which is of the list StdDetails. I am trying to use comparator ....

```java
Comparator<StdResponse> cmp = new Comparator<StdResponse>() {

            public int compare(List<StdResponse> o1, <StdResponse> o2) {
                return o1.getStdDetails().
```

not able to get the value of startDate. Please help, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want the list sorted. Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: The first argument to `compare` should not be a list. `public int compare(StdResponse o1, StdResponse o2) { ...}`

Comment: If you want to compare `StdResponse` objects than you correctly are trying to create `Comparator<StdResponse>` but that means its `compare` method should also take `StdResponse` objects as arguments. `public int compare(List<StdResponse> o1, <StdResponse> o2){...}` doesn't fulfill that requirement, it should be `public int compare(StdResponse o1, StdResponse o2){...}`.